# Login/Signup on the same page

Tags: php, html

Currently I have a login form like this [This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTUt.jpg):

```
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
        <div id="formContent">
    <!-- Tabs Titles -->
    <h2 class="active"> Sign In </h2>
    <h2 class="inactive underlineHover">Sign Up </h2>

    <!-- Icon -->
    <div class="fadeIn first">
      <img src="abc-logo.png" id="icon" alt="User Icon" style='height: 25%; width: 25%; object-fit: contain' />
    </div>

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="login">
      <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="password">
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
    </form>

    <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
    <div id="formFooter">
      <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
```

How can I add some sort of "switch function(?)" that when the user press "Sign up" is shows sign up boxes insted?

Comment: down voted because you should have taken some time searching about this functionality before turning to Stack Overflow :)  
I don't want to be rude or harsh here, but try to research a bit before posting for help on this community platform. This way it will help you alot in your searching skills :)  
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

**You can use tabs** try this,

```css
/*
 CSS for the main interaction
*/
.tabset > input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200vw;
}

.tabset .tab-panel {
  display: none;
}

.tabset > input:first-child:checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:first-child,
.tabset > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(2),
.tabset > input:nth-child(5):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(3),
.tabset > input:nth-child(7):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(4),
.tabset > input:nth-child(9):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(5),
.tabset > input:nth-child(11):checked ~ .tab-panels > .tab-panel:nth-child(6) {
  display: block;
}

/*
 Styling
*/
body {
  font: 16px/1.5em "Overpass", "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tabset > label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 15px 25px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.tabset > label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #8d8d8d;
}

.tabset > label:hover,
.tabset > input:focus + label {
  color: #06c;
}

.tabset > label:hover::after,
.tabset > input:focus + label::after,
.tabset > input:checked + label::after {
  background: #06c;
}

.tabset > input:checked + label {
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.tab-panel {
  padding: 30px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*
 Demo purposes only
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.tabset {
  max-width: 65em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabset">
  <!-- Tab 1 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab1" aria-controls="marzen" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Märzen</label>
  <!-- Tab 2 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab2" aria-controls="rauchbier">
  <label for="tab2">Rauchbier</label>
  
  <div class="tab-panels">
    <section id="marzen" class="tab-panel">
      <h2>Login page</h2>
      
  </section>
    
    <section id="dunkles" class="tab-panel">
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      
    </section>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is also a more quick way of doing. check this one as well @AnnaBD

Answer (score 1):

First, you need your sign in and sign up text to make it buttons and after that you need to make two divs first will contain your sign in section and second sign up section and add at sign up div `display: none;` and you can use javascript with add event listener to the sign up button, basically when you click on the sign up button your sign in box will disappear and sign up box appear.
Something like that.

```js
let signInButton = document.querySelector(".firstButton");
let signUpButton = document.querySelector(".secondButton");

let signIn = document.querySelector(".firstBox"); // firstBox is the class of sign in div you can add which name you want
let signUp = document.querySelector(".secondBox");

signUpButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  signIn.style.display = "none";
  signUp.style.display = "block";
  
})

signInButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  signUp.style.display = "block";
  signIn.style.display = "block";
})
```

Also you can add some animation to make it smoother.

- To make it more clear to you, the classes from querySelector doesn't exist you need to make your own divs with some classes and change with them on the JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this using Javascript:

Below your Login Form you add divs around the elements of the Login and Signup Forms, and for the Signup Form you add the attribute `style="display:none"` to hide it.

```
<!-- Login Form -->
<div id=loginElements>
 <form>
  
    <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="login">
    <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
 </form>
</div>
<div id=signupElements style="display:none">
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="signup" class="fadeIn second" name="signup" placeholder="signup">
    <input type="text" id="signupPassword" class="fadeIn third" name="signupPassword" placeholder="password" style="display:none">
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Sign Up">
 </form>
</div>
```

and then you add `onclick` functions to the tabs titles that changes what is displayed. Example that hides the Login Form and shows the Signup Form:

```
<h2 class="inactive underlineHover" onclick=showSignUp()>Sign Up </h2>
```

and implement it like this:

```
function showSignUp() {
  // Hide login form
  var loginElements = document.getElementById("loginElements");
  loginElements.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

  // Display signup form
  var signupElements = document.getElementById("signupElements");
  signupElements.setAttribute('style', '');
}
```

You can implement the function that hides the Signup Form and shows the Login Form similar to this.
Also you probably need to change the classes of the tab titles so that the correct one is displayed as active. This is also very similar to the code above, you just need to give them ids, so you can access the elements with Javascript and then use `.setAttribute('class', 'active');` to set the correct class.

Comment: Instead of hiding each individual input, why not putting each form in a separate div and try hiding those divs using your snippet :)

Comment: Try to apply @TudorAlexandru snippet on your code by separating each form in their respective div.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! I've updated my answer with divs around the form elements.